# Sample k-fold cross validation in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I want to test k-fold (k=3) cross-validation in Python

I got this code from the web

```
import nltk # needed for Naive-Bayes
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold

# data is an array with our already pre-processed dataset examples
kf = KFold(n_splits=3)
sum = 0
for train, test in kf.split(data):
    train_data = np.array(data)[train]
    test_data = np.array(data)[test]
    classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
    sum += nltk.classify.accuracy(classifier, test_data)
average = sum/3
```

and add:

```
data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

error result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/david/PycharmProjects/iranian-01/pandas_test.py", line 12, in <module>
classifier = nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/classify/naivebayes.py", line 194, in train
for featureset, label in labeled_featuresets:
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

please help me to solve this

Comment: data was an array, you changed it to a tuple. Why?

Comment: ٍdited to:
     data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]

Comment: But I still have errors

Comment: You can correct it ?

Comment: Well your data is a 1x5 array. You need a matrix of nsamples x ndimensions

Comment: Also, you are trying to train a classifier with a vector of values. Where is your vector of classes? How do you expect KFold to split a vector?

Comment: Ok , i change : data = [10, 20, 30] for 3fold cross validation

Comment: I would recommend first taking a look at one of the examples provided in sklearn to understand what is KFold and how the data is expected to be. Then you can change the code to add your own data.

Comment: I am a novice in Python , 
Thanks for the guide, but I do not notice much,
Can you tell me how to fix it to work?
I just want to do a very simple k-fold

Answer (score 0):

You should to fit your data before training and testing.
i.e. you are going to make a 3-fold cross validation to these data

```
data = [10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
```

so, the result will be a floating point number when the compiler splitting it.
I advice you to work with [numpy](http://www.numpy.org) rather than a Python purely arrays, to be able to use the pre-defined functions in this library.